# Set dependsOn to previous stage without hardcoding the value in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using Azure Pipelines, how can you set `dependsOn` to the previous stage without hardcoding the value?

Is there some sort of pre-defined variable I can use? I only saw for the current stage and not previous stages.

My pipeline is performing a Terraform deployment. The first (build) stages are running a `terraform plan` in parallel for each environment which would then be used by the (deploy) stages that are running `terraform apply` using the plan file in each environment sequentially.

I am using two different templates for the plan (build) and apply (deploy) stages. I am currently using a parameter to specify the `dependsOn` list values where I need to specify all the plan (build) stages explicitly however for the apply (deploy) stages, I was hoping to default value of the parameter to something like **$(Build.PreviousStage)** to make it a bit more elegant.

```yaml
# azure-pipelines.yml

# LINES REMOVED #

stages:
  # Terraform Plan (DevTest)
  - template: templates/plan.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: DevTest-Terraform
      environment: DevTest

  # Terraform Plan (Stage)
  - template: templates/plan.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: Stage-Terraform
      environment: Stage

  # Terraform Plan (Prod)
  - template: templates/plan.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: Prod-Terraform
      environment: Prod

  # Terraform Deploy (DevTest)
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: DevTest-Terraform
      depends_on:
        - DevTest_Plan
        - Stage_Plan
        - Prod_Plan
      environment: DevTest

  # Terraform Deploy (Stage)
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: Stage-Terraform
      depends_on:
        - DevTest_Deploy
      environment: Stage

  # Terraform Deploy (Prod)
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: Prod-Terraform
      depends_on:
        - Stage_Deploy
      environment: Prod
```

```yaml
# ./templates/deploy.yml

parameters:
  - name: az_service_connection
    type: string
  - name: depends_on
    type: object
  - name: environment
    type: string

stages:
  # Terraform Deploy
  - stage: ${{ parameters.environment }}_Deploy
    displayName: Terraform Deploy (${{ parameters.environment }})
    condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI', 'Manual'))
    dependsOn:
      ${{ parameters.depends_on }}

# LINES REMOVED #
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An if condition to check whether the `depends_on` parameter is empty while also setting the parameter default to "" allowed me to workaround this issue allowing me to set the `depends_on` parameter for the first DEV deploy stage while not setting it for the others.

As @Krzysztof Madej stated in his answer/comments, no such variable exists to set the previous stage for `dependsOn` but will automatically depend on the previous stage if not set.

```yaml
# azure-pipelines.yml

# LINES REMOVED #

stages:
  # Terraform Plan (DevTest)
  - template: templates/plan.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: DevTest-Terraform
      environment: DevTest

  # Terraform Plan (Stage)
  - template: templates/plan.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: Stage-Terraform
      environment: Stage

  # Terraform Plan (Prod)
  - template: templates/plan.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: Prod-Terraform
      environment: Prod

  # Terraform Deploy (DevTest)
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: DevTest-Terraform
      depends_on:
        - DevTest_Plan
        - Stage_Plan
        - Prod_Plan
      environment: DevTest

  # Terraform Deploy (Stage)
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: Stage-Terraform
      environment: Stage

  # Terraform Deploy (Prod)
  - template: templates/deploy.yml
    parameters:
      az_service_connection: Prod-Terraform
      environment: Prod
```

```yaml
# templates/deploy.yml

parameters:
  - name: az_service_connection
    type: string
  - name: depends_on
    type: object
    default:
  - name: environment
    type: string

stages:
  # Terraform Deploy
  - stage: ${{ parameters.environment }}_Deploy
    displayName: Terraform Deploy (${{ parameters.environment }})
    condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI', 'Manual'))
    ${{ if ne(length(parameters.depends_on), 0) }}:
      dependsOn:
        ${{ parameters.depends_on }}
```

Comment: If you have `dependsOn: []` it wont add the depends on it seems. Using 
`${{ if parameters.depends_on}}:` Seems to work in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable like the one mentioned by you, but

> When you define multiple stages in a pipeline, by default, they run one after the other in the order in which you define them in the YAML file. Pipelines must contain at least one stage with no dependencies.

and

```yaml
# if you do not use a dependsOn keyword, stages run in the order they are defined
stages:
- stage: QA
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...

- stage: Prod
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...
```

As it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-dependencies). So if you do not define dependsOn stage should be implicitly depends on previous stage.

Comment: One thing I mentioned but didn't outline well was that the first set of stages running the build/plan steps use `dependsOn: []` to run as parallel jobs. Without specifying the `dependsOn` for the first deploy/apply stages to DEV, it will start once `Prod_Plan` is complete however the stage requires `DevTest_Plan` to be completed first.

Comment: In that way, I am afraid that this is not possible. Variables are simple string, and you need an array.